# How to match a TimeSpan against "hh:mm"?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

My question is branched into A and B.

In my viewmodel, I am defining selectable times to be passed to a dropdown in the view, like this:

```
public List<string> SelectableTimes => new List<string>
{
    "00:00", "00:15", "00:30" //, ... and so on.
};
```

... and displaying them like this:

```
<select asp-for="TimeFrom" 
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SelectableTimes, Model.TimeFrom))">
</select>
```

The `TimeFrom`-property of the model is a `TimeSpan`:

```
public TimeSpan TimeFrom { get; set; }
```

**Question A)** How can I select the correct time in the dropdown? The first option (00:00) is always selected.

If I change the `SelectableTimes` to include seconds, thus altering the premise of question A, like this:

```
public List<string> SelectableTimes => new List<string>
{
    "00:00:00", "00:15:00", "00:30:00" //, ... and so on.
};
```

... it works, but I don't want to display seconds in the dropdown.

**Question B)** Is it possible to format away the seconds? I have tried adding `.ToString(@"hh\:mm")`, but the seconds are still being displayed:

```
<select asp-for="TimeFrom" 
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SelectableTimes, Model.TimeFrom.ToString(@"hh\:mm")))">
</select>
```

Comment: Try populating your `SelectableTimes` with `TimeSpan` and change your `Select` to  `new SelectList(Model.SelectableTimes, Model.TimeFrom, "{0:hh:mm}");`

Answer (score 0):

Try solution below:

```
public class TimeVM
{
    public List<TimeSpanVM> SelectableTimes => new List<TimeSpanVM>()
                {
                       new TimeSpanVM{Value = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) , Label = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0).ToString("hh\\:mm")},
                       new TimeSpanVM{Value = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0) , Label = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0).ToString("hh\\:mm")},
                       new TimeSpanVM{Value = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0) , Label = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0).ToString("hh\\:mm")}
                };

    public TimeSpan TimeFrom { get; set; } = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);

}

public class TimeSpanVM
{
    public TimeSpan Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateTimeVM">
            <select asp-for="TimeFrom"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.SelectableTimes,"Value", "Label" , Model.TimeFrom))"></select>   

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```